# Create dataframe with vector elements in one cell of it - Rstudio

Tags: dataframe, vector, indexing, rstudio, element

I'm new to R and I think this is kind of easy but I have not found a specific answer to this. I'm trying to reproduce a dataframe df with just one column called path.vec that is collecting paths of vector elements. 
Each cell of this path.vec in df can be a simple element of a vector or a vector of elements.

**#this is an example of path**

```
vector <- c("apple", "banana", "melon")
```

**#below is my one element per cell vector**

```
df <- data.frame(
  path.vec = c("apple", "banana", "melon")
)
```

**#adding the path to the vector**

**#I have tried append(), code below, but this is splitting my vector into 1 element per row while I want to keep my path, when a path is there, all together in one cell **

```
append(path.vec, vector, after = length(path.vec) )
```

[1] `"apple"  "banana" "melon"  "apple"  "banana" "melon"  "apple"  "banana" "melon"`

Eventually I would like something like

```
path.vec = c("apple","banana","melon", c("apple", "banana", "melon"))
```

```
   [1] `"apple"  "banana" "melon"  c("apple", "banana", "melon")  '
```

or

```
   path.vec
 1 apple
 2 lemon
 3 melon
 4 c("appple", "banana", "melon")
```

I need this dataframe as a reproducible example of a real dataframe already structured exactly like this where I need to investigate indices of a specific element in a vector of elements.

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

just for everyone reference I have solved this with list():

```
       df_1 <- data.frame(id=1:4,
           path.vec = I(list("apple", "lemon", "melon",c("apple", "banana","melon")))

                        )
```

The list column has to be wrapped inside the function I. This will protect it from several conversions taking place in data.frame and ensures that matrices are inserted as single columns.

output:

```
id  path.vec
1   apple
2   lemon
3   melon
4   c("apple", "banana", "melon")
```

thank you!